# Gmail API service account unauthorized_client error even with domain-wide authority

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have read extensively on how to access GCP Gmail API using service account and have given it domain-wide authority, using the instruction here:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106

Here is my service account:

[image]

Here is the scopes added to the domain-wide authority.  You can see that the ID matches the service account.

[image]

One thing I notice is that my GCP project is an internal project, I havent' published it or anything, yet when I added the scope, it is not showing the service account email name but the project name.  Does it make any difference?  Do I need to set anything here? In the OAuth Consent Screen, I see the name of the project is being defined there.  I have added all same scope on this screen too, not sure if it make any difference.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery
credentials_file = get_credentials('gmail.json')
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_file, scopes=scopes)
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject("abc@mydomain.com")
GMAIL_SERVICE = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
labels = GMAIL_SERVICE.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
```

Error message:

> Google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('unauthorized_client: Client is
> unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client
> not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', {'error':
> 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Client is unauthorized to
> retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for
> any of the scopes requested.'})

Comment: I am not sure, but I looked in my similar code (which I use inside cloud functions, thus there is json credentials), and I use "discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)" function with "cache_discovery=False" parameter...

Comment: sorry, mistyped - as I use my code in the cloud function, I don't use any json files with credentials for a specific service account, which has gmail api permissions.

Comment: If you don't use any json file with credential, where does your permission come from?

Comment: I added an answer providing an example how it works

Comment: What was the resolution to this problem? Did the answer work for you or did it have problems?

Comment: Running into the exact same issue. Posted  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76926042/how-do-i-debug-unauthorized-client-error-in-a-google-api-call  with my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I can answer precisely on the original question (I think not), but here how things are done in cloud functions developed by me. The following particular code snippet is written/adopted for this answer, and it was not tested:

```
import os
import google.auth
import google.auth.iam
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.exceptions import MutualTLSChannelError
from google.auth.transport import requests
import googleapiclient.discovery

from google.cloud import error_reporting

GMAIL_SERV_ACCOUNT = "A service account which makes the API CALL"
OAUTH_TOKEN_URI = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
GMAIL_SCOPES_LIST = ["https://mail.google.com/"] # for example
GMAIL_USER = "User's email address, who's email we would like to access. abc@mydomain.com - from your question"

# inside the cloud function code:

    local_credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
    local_credentials.refresh(requests.Request())

    signer = google.auth.iam.Signer(requests.Request(), local_credentials, GMAIL_SERV_ACCOUNT)
    delegate_credentials = service_account.Credentials(
        signer, GMAIL_SERV_ACCOUNT, OAUTH_TOKEN_URI, scopes=GMAIL_SCOPES_LIST, subject=GMAIL_USER)
    delegate_credentials.refresh(requests.Request())

    try:
        email_api_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            'gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegate_credentials, cache_discovery=False)
    except MutualTLSChannelError as err:
        # handle it somehow, for example (stupid, artificial)
        ER = error_reporting.Client(service="my-app", version=os.getenv("K_REVISION", "0"))
        ER.report_exception()
        return 0
```

So, the idea is to use my (or 'local') cloud function's service account to create credentials of a dedicated service account (GMAIL_SERV_ACCOUNT - which is used in many different cloud functions running under many different 'local' service accounts); then use that 'delegate' service account to get API service access.

I don't remember if the GMAIL_SERV_ACCOUNT should have any specific IAM roles. But I think the 'local' cloud function's service account should get `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` for it.

Updated:

Some clarification on the IAM role. In terraform (I use it for my CICD) for a given functional component, it looks:

```
# this service account is an 'external' for the given functional component, 
# it is managed in another repository and terraform state file
# so we should get it at first 
data "google_service_account" "gmail_srv_account" {
 project    = "some project id"
 account_id = "actual GMAIL_SERV_ACCOUNT account"
}

# now we provide IAM role for that working with it
# where 'google_service_account.local_cf_sa' is the service account, 
# under which the given cloud function is running
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "iam_token_creator_gmail_sa" {
 service_account_id = data.google_service_account.gmail_srv_account.name
 role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
 member             = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.local_cf_sa.email}"
 depends_on         = [
   google_service_account.local_cf_sa,
 ]
}
```