# GCP - Python Create cloud function call Gmail Api Storage Account

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

On my local machine I have 2 python scripts, google.py which help me with gmail_api, then my program which takes csv files from email inbox then send those csv files to my GCP storage account, currently I run this from my local machine, I have 2 json files, one to get access gmail_api and the other storage_account to get access to my bucket which is my destination.

I want to create a cloud function on gcp but right now I am calling those mentioned json files from local machine, what I need to change to put my python scripts on a cloud function and call gmail api and storage account from there?
Here i am calling my storage account

```
 os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'storage_account.json'
```

Here calling my gmail api json:

```
CLIENT_FILE = 'credentials.json'
```

Once I put my code on the cloud function what is need it to call not the json files, instead call the locations of those accesses?

```
import os
import base64
from typing import List
import time
from datetime import datetime
from Google import create_service
from google.cloud import storage

class GmailException(Exception):
    """gmail base exception class"""

class NoEmailFound(GmailException):
    """no email found"""

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'storage_account.json'

storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket_name = 'mybucketname'

def search_emails(query_stirng: str, label_ids: List=None):
    try:
        message_list_response = service.users().messages().list(
            userId='me',
            labelIds=label_ids,
            q=query_string
        ).execute()

        message_items = message_list_response.get('messages')
        next_page_token = message_list_response.get('nextPageToken')
        
        while next_page_token:
            message_list_response = service.users().messages().list(
                userId='me',
                labelIds=label_ids,
                q=query_string,
                pageToken=next_page_token
            ).execute()

            message_items.extend(message_list_response.get('messages'))
            next_page_token = message_list_response.get('nextPageToken')
        return message_items
    except Exception as e:
        raise NoEmailFound('No emails returned')

def get_file_data(message_id, attachment_id, file_name, new_Location):
    response = service.users().messages().attachments().get(
        userId='me',
        messageId=message_id,
        id=attachment_id
    ).execute()
    
    file_data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(response.get('data').encode('UTF-8'))
    return file_data

def get_message_detail(message_id, msg_format='metadata', metadata_headers: List=None):
    message_detail = service.users().messages().get(
        userId='me',
        id=message_id,
        format=msg_format,
        metadataHeaders=metadata_headers
    ).execute()
    return message_detail


"""
Upload File
"""
def upload_to_bucket(blob_name, file_path, bucket_name):
    try:
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
        blob.upload_from_filename(file_path)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False


def save_file_data(email_messages):
    for email_message in email_messages: 
        messageDetail = get_message_detail(email_message['id'], msg_format='full', metadata_headers=['parts'])  
        headers=messageDetail["payload"]["headers"]
        subjects= [j['value'] for j in headers if j["name"]=="Subject"]
        subject=subjects[0]      
        save_location=subject
        messageDetailPayload = messageDetail.get('payload') 
        if 'parts' in messageDetailPayload: 
            for msgPayload in messageDetailPayload['parts']: 
                file_name = msgPayload['filename'] 
                filetype = ".csv"
                if file_name.find(filetype) != -1:
                    body = msgPayload['body'] 
                    if 'attachmentId' in body: 
                        attachment_id = body['attachmentId'] 
                        attachment_content = get_file_data(email_message['id'], attachment_id, file_name, save_location)             
                        with open(file_name, "wb") as binary_file:
                            binary_file.write(attachment_content)
                            upload_to_bucket(save_location+'/'+file_name, file_name,bucket_name)
                            print(f'File {file_name} is saved at {save_location}{bucket_name}') 
        time.sleep(0.5)
    

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    CLIENT_FILE = 'credentials.json' 
    API_NAME = 'gmail' 
    API_VERSION = 'v1' 
    SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/'] 
    service = create_service(CLIENT_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES) 
    query_string = 'has:attachment' 
    email_messages = search_emails(query_string) 
    save_file_data(email_messages)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very shortly:

You might like to create service account under which your cloud function should run.

Then, you probably would like to delegate domain wide authority to that service account.

Details are here: [Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) and here: [Control API access with domain-wide delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en)

Here is a Stack Overflow question which described this approach - [Gmail API service account unauthorized_client error even with domain-wide authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144871/gmail-api-service-account-unauthorized-client-error-even-with-domain-wide-author)

And then, in that question, there is answer (provided by me some time ago) - how to get access to the gmail account without any private keys from inside a cloud function.

So far, when you run something inside GCP (rather than from your local machine), it may be a good idea to avoid using security keys if possible.

Comment: Hi, and what if I just replace the .json with the key from the service account?

Comment: you can try... at the same time - where are you going to store it? And your service account should have relevant permission (independently from where you store the json file).