# How to authenticate to Gmail API in GCP environment without explicitly referring to a service account file or info

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I am writing a script that will authenticate to the Gmail API, pull some emails and transform some email data. I can get this working locally since I have the service account file which I am creating a credentials object from and then referencing in the Gmail API, however since this will be running in Google Cloud Product (GCP) the credentials are stored in the environment.

I need to somehow either modify the code to not reference credentials or retrieve a credentials object in the environment.

The code below works locally, however where I am creating the `credentials` object, I either need to retrieve that from the environment or authenticate in a different way when creating the `delegated_credentials` and `service` objects.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'secret.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)



delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('someone@gmail.com')
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
```

As an example, when using the google cloud storage API, I create the client in GCP as follow:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
```

Comment: Some time ago I provided an example (in python) who I work with the Gmail API from inside a GCP cloud function - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144871/gmail-api-service-account-unauthorized-client-error-even-with-domain-wide-author/72147040#72147040  It might be not exactly would you would like, but hopefully can give you some hints. It also useful to check the question there, as it provides some details on the 'delegation' process.

Comment: Are you telling me that you got service accounts working with a standard gmail user?  This is not a google workspace domain user?

Comment: Whatever you mean by "Google Cloud Product", you might have to provide the JSON file, even when passing a path. Please come back when you have an actual problem or question ...